# How do I add a custom label in ```react-chartjs-2``` as shown in the file?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, react-chartjs

Soo I've been working with react-chart-js and I want to achieve a responsive version of the following chart,

[image]

The chart is perfectly fine but I want to add labels as shown in the picture, for now my approach is to give the whole chart a relative position and use absolute on labels to point them appropriately, but I can't seem to achieve that same effect on multiple devices especially once the width of graph varies. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Also, I hid the default labels from `react-chartsjs-2` using default technique.